# Animated blocks in AOS and NUXT JS tends to disappear whenever the page reloads

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, aos.js

I'm working on a project and using [AOS](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) animation but all div blocks that have an animation on them disappear whenever I refresh the page. I want to trigger a function whenever the page is refreshed so I can use the `AOS.refresh()`. Is there any way to do this in nuxt.js or maybe a way to go around this AOS bug?

UPDATE:
here's an example this is how the page looks before reloading:
[image]

then after reloading:
[image]

As you can see. the elements that still appear after the reloading are the ones without AOS animation.

Additionally, if you focus your eyes on the sidebar, notice I have a home page. this problem happens literally everywhere except the home page. When I go to the home page then I go back to other pages the problem basically disappears.

Comment: You should also ask on the AOS project because they might have a standard way to have that happen automatically.

Comment: I already looked and I found the problem in github in the issue section and it seems like there's not way to fix it in AOS unless I fork the repo and fix it myself

Comment: This seems more likely an issue with data fetching or lifecycles actually. Do you have a github or something hosted on codesandbox to show us? Not sure what to get from those screenshots.

Comment: I'm not really getting any errors when refreshing the page. I don't have a codesandbox to show you though...

Comment: I could give you the link to my repo so you can check it out of you want @kissu

Comment: Let's see if it can be solved quickly. Feel free to edit your question with the repo link.

Comment: Updated. the project is kinda big right now so I hope you can find it. If you need help finding something please tell me.

Comment: Damn, pretty huge work asked by your school here. A bit too much code to read. Maybe try to give us the relevant code. And also, contact an admin if you want to remove the things that you've edited, otherwise it will stay visible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is your bug coming from but so far, the homepage of the library achieves to have an animation on a page refresh. Maybe it is a lifecycle code issue at some point. Maybe post some for us to help you debug this one.

To my knowledge, there is no way of watching if your webpage is actually refreshed because there is nothing related to state before this. The only somehow useful thing that may be used sometime is `this.$router.history._startLocation`, which will give you the first path your webapp was loaded on.
Not sure if it may help you anyhow.

Also, you can maybe give a shot to this [library in VueJS](https://github.com/vycoder/vue-animate-onscroll) and wire it to Nuxt. Should behave pretty much the same.

Comment: I have updated the question please check it and tell me what you think